# PyQt Get cell from TableView with header label

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview, qheaderview

I currently load the results of an SQL query into a TableView.

```
self.projectModel = QSqlQueryModel()
self.projectModel.setQuery(sql,db)
```

I then need to select a specific cell based on the header label (geometry). This column will move position depending on the different table that is search.

When the user clicks anywhere on the row (NOT the cell of geometry column) I would like to select the geometry column cell.

At the moment I have a this associated with the tableView

```
self.dlg.tableView.clicked.connect(self.cellClicked)
```

And in that function I have

```
row = self.projectModel.currentIndex()
```

If I use QTableView.model(row, column) to select the index, I have to speciify the row and column number. However, this would vary so I would want to do QTableView.model(row, 'geometry') however the model expects integers.

Any solutions?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems all you need is a method to find a column from its header label, i.e. something like:

```
def columnFromLabel(self, label):
    model = self.table.horizontalHeader().model()
    for column in range(model.columnCount()):
        if model.headerData(column, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal) == label:
            return column
    return -1
```